# python nlp - how to start token id from 1 after a blank line for every sentence

Tags: python-2.7

I have tokenized text in a .txt file as follows:

```
token_1
token_2
token_3


token_4
token_5
```

Tokens 1, 2 and 3 constitute the first sentence and token 4 and 5 constitute the second sentence. There are two blank lines between the last token of the first sentence and the first token of the second sentence. (Actually I have two versions of that file, one has two blank lines between the sentences and the other one has no blank lines)

I need the token id to start from 1 for every sentence.
My output should be as follows:

```
1 token_1
2 token_2
3 token_3

1 token_4
2 token_5
```

I know I could get an incrementing id for all by

```
id = 0
for token in doc:
id += 1
```

but the id continues as 4 and 5 in the second sentence.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your counter at the end of a sentence. You may find the end of a sentence using a sentence detector (or two blank lines in your case).

In,

```
for token in doc:
  id=id+1
```

if the detected token is a newline, reset the id to 1.

Comment: I have another file with the whole text one sentence in one line.

Comment: I have another file with the whole text with each sentence in one line. How can I read those lines one by one and assign an id to each token? file.readlines() creates a list of sentences but the tokenizer module that I am using wants a unicode text rather than a list and gives an error.

Comment: Do a for-each to parse through the list and you will get strings which you may use.